# remove specific element from array with duplicate react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

well, I have this reducer which has 2 actions: add an item and remove the item. 
add item work fine but the problem is with remove item, when I use filter method it will remove all items with the same name(duplicate), but I want to remove only the clicked element.

I tried to use splice method by passing the item index as payload instead of a name, creating new array same as basket items and applying splice method to this array but the problem is when I assign the new array to basket items it changes but doesn't re-render the items!

hope anyone can help thank u!

```js
import {ADD_ITEM,REMOVE_ITEM} from "./Actions-Type"
var initialState ={
    baskeitems:[" Strawberry"," Blueberry","Blueberry","Blueberry","Strawberry"]
};

function Rootreducer (state=initialState,action){
    if (action.type === ADD_ITEM) {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                baskeitems: state.baskeitems.concat(action.payload)
            })
}
else{
    if(action.type===REMOVE_ITEM){
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            baskeitems: state.baskeitems.filter((item)=>{return(item!==action.payload)})
        })
    }
    else{
        return state;
    }
}

}
export default Rootreducer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fine to use splice as long as you restructure the array using the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator. Your reducer can be expressed as follows using this syntax.

```
import {ADD_ITEM,REMOVE_ITEM} from "./Actions-Type"
var initialState ={
    baskeitems:[" Strawberry"," Blueberry","Blueberry","Blueberry","Strawberry"]
};

function Rootreducer (state=initialState,action){
    if (action.type === ADD_ITEM)
            return { ...state, baskeitems: [ ...state.baskeitems, action.payload ] }

    if(action.type===REMOVE_ITEM) {
            state.baskeitems.splice(action.payload, 1)
            return { ...state, baskeitems: [ ...state.baskeitems ] }
    }

    return state;
}

}
export default Rootreducer;
```

With this method, the payload has to be the index to splice at.
Note that there is no purpose to using `else` statements as the `return` statement will end execution when the action type matches.

Comment: its giving me this error baskeitems' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Sorry my bad, fixed.

Comment: well its work but now this remove all elements and leave the the clicked one!

Comment: my bad again :) fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Relying on their `index` + splice may introduce unintended bugs. For example, if you render the items sorted in order, that differ from their initial state.

I would recommend you to assign a unique identifier to your items initially and later use the filter function, in order to remove the item by id.

Initially, you can assign an `id` to all the items using their index (it's an option to use [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) for id too):

```
const basketitems = ["Strawberry", "Blueberry", "Blueberry", "Blueberry", "Strawberry"]


const initialState = {
  basketitems: basketitems.map((item, index) => ({ id: index, name: item }))
}
```

Comment: i know it can be done  with  unique identifier using filter method but is there other method to achieve it without adding  unique identifier !

Comment: As your `basketitems` names are not unique, I don't know other safer method better than having auto generated `id`.

Comment: It's fine to splice by index. Sorting itself is an action that should be sent through the reducer. If you are sorting in the view, you are doing the view wrong. I.e. sorting is a stateful action. You are changing the order of occurrence.

Comment: @AvinKavish I cannot agree. What would happen if you list the same items twice on the same page, having different sorting? It's better to keep the sorted items `ids` in another Store key, without changing the initial items structure. Also having sorting on one component, should not rerender the same items on other component, because of sorting.

Comment: In that case, a solution like yours is needed, I'm just trying to answer op's question. Not extend it to a real world scenario where there are other complications. I'm sure he already knows to handle those. Let's face it, in a real app, items have ids anyway. There is no need to make them.

Comment: Also in a real-world scenario, the sorting goes hand in hand with pagination and filters, and there aren't any points to change and reorder the Items in the Store. A better approach would be to keep a separate list of resulted `ids`. Using `splice` by index having obvious drawbacks and yes - we're talking about real scenarios here. As developers, we're trying to give our best to prevent our app of side effects, and the approach you suggest (relying on the index) - for sure introduces such ones.